# Как полностью заполнить блок изображением?

Tags: html, css

[image: блоки с img]

2ое изображение не заполняет блок. Как это сделать?

```css
.photos__img {
  width: 100%;
}
.photos__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .25s;
  &: hover {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
}
.photos__item {
  padding: 0;
}
.photos__btn,
.photos__desc {
  color: #fff;
}
.photos__content .photos__btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: @orange 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  color: @orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 photos__item">
  <img class="photos__img" src="/img/Глубина--.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="photos__content">
    <h3 class="photos__title">title</h3>
    <p class="photos__desc">photos__desc</p>
    <button class="photos__btn">Посмотреть</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 photos__item">
  <img class="photos__img" src="/img/IMG_1372-острв.jpg" alt="">
  <div class="photos__content">
    <h3 class="photos__title">title</h3>
    <p class="photos__desc">photos__desc</p>
    <button class="photos__btn">Посмотреть</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в смысле растянуть?

Comment: @Isaev не. нужно чтобы изображение влезло в блок,можно его даже увеличить,чтобы не было белой полосы снизу. Но не растягивайте, пропорции должны быть сохранены

Comment: @StepanIvanov, вставьте изображения фоном блока и задайте размер     `background-size: cover;`

Answer (score 5):

Все просто:
Замените картинку

```
<img class="photos__img" src="/img/Глубина--.jpg" alt="">
```

на блок

```
<div class="you_img_1"></div>
```

css

```
.you_img_1 {
  background-image: url(you_img.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Свойство `background-size: cover`заполняет изображением весь блок

Comment: да это как один из вариантов. Но допустим если будет 100 изображений, то для них нужно будет 100 классов писать?

Answer (score 1):

На момент публикации ответа, свойство не поддерживается браузерами ИЕ и Эдж, для Оперы мини необходимо использовать префикс `-o-`. Покрытие рынка браузеров — 79,1%.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.photos__item {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="photos__item" src="http://pipsum.com/400x200.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, добавить запускаемый пример? И желательно добавить, что это свойство `object-fit` не поддерживается IE.

Comment: добавил запускаемый пример

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас очень много изображений, а их вывод происходит путем какого либо серверного языка, то можно поступить еще иначе

```
<div class="full_bg" style="background-image: url(you_img_1.jpg);"></div>
<div class="full_bg" style="background-image: url(you_img_2.jpg);"></div>
<div class="full_bg" style="background-image: url(you_img_3.jpg);"></div>
<div class="full_bg" style="background-image: url(you_img_4.jpg);"></div>
```

css

```
.full_bg{
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вам нужно именно `img`, то можно для картинки сделать `position: absolute` и дальше играться:

```css
.photos {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.photos__img {
  /* Эти стили для фото */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(calc((100% - 140px) / -2)); /* Это что бы картинка отображалась по середине */
}
.photos__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 1%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .25s;
  &: hover {
    opacity: 1;
    padding-top: 5%;
  }
}
.photos__item {
  position: relative;
  /* Добавить это */
  padding: 0;
  width: 140px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Это */
}
.photos__btn,
.photos__desc {
  color: #fff;
}
.photos__content .photos__btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: @orange 1px solid;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  color: @orange;

}
```

```html
<div class="photos">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 photos__item">
    <img class="photos__img" src="http://i.imgur.com/Sp443QO.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="photos__content">
      <h3 class="photos__title">title</h3>
      <p class="photos__desc">photos__desc</p>
      <button class="photos__btn">Посмотреть</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 photos__item">
    <img class="photos__img" src="http://i.imgur.com/8fryvwd.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="photos__content">
      <h3 class="photos__title">title</h3>
      <p class="photos__desc">photos__desc</p>
      <button class="photos__btn">Посмотреть</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```